# C++ vector subtract elements

Tags: c++, vector

I have a vector like this:

```
std::vector<float> v {5120.2, 5140.2, 5500.2, 5482.0, 5802.2};
```

I want to subtract all elements:

```
5120.2 - 5140.2 = -20.0
5120.2 - 5500.2 = -380.0
5120.2 - 5482.0 = -358.2
5120.2 - 5802.2 = -682.0
5140.2 - 5500.2 = -360.0
5140.2 - 5482.0 = -341.8
5140.2 - 5802.2 = -562.0
5500.2 - 5482.0 =   18.0
5500.2 - 5802.0 = -301.8
5482.0 - 5802.0 = -320.0
```

I need only absolute values.

How can I solve this with `std::transform`?Or any other way,more simpler the better.

Comment: Substract every element from every element or every element from first element?

Comment: Note that particularly on a 64 bit system, a std::vector<float> may turn out less efficient than std::vector<double>.

Comment: @user2475983 Every element from every element,yes!

Comment: @RichardRublev won't that give you just zeros ?

Comment: You should give the whole result vector it's confusing...

Comment: @Quentin No,I want mutual subtraction,If results were saved in matrix,probably zeros would be on a diogonal!

Comment: This must be one of the worst specifications I've ever seen. Why don't you simplify the input numbers, and specify what you want to happen for the outlying element, and what happens if the vector has 0 or 1 elements?

Comment: @RichardRublev oh, so `(a, b, c)` becomes `(a-a, a-b, a-c, b-a, b-b, b-c, c-a, c-b, c-c)`, that is, a cartesian product ?

Comment: @Bathsheba  Vector has 1484 elements,I have just written 5 elements for simplicity.I do not get this worst specification problem.

Comment: @Quentin Well,yes tht is tru.

Comment: You've got four answers with completely different behaviour. The one you chose (whose quality or validity I do not dispute) does *not* fit the requirements you have provided. Please make sure that your questions are well-defined enough so as to actually be answerable without guesswork about the problem at hand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use `std::transform` you can use a lambda like that in one line :

```
std::transform(v.begin(), v.end(), v.begin(), 
  [&](float a) { static float init{v[0]}; return init - a; });
```

**<kbd>[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/77bd6198f7e1a1a7)</kbd>**

Result given is

> 0;-20;-380;-361.8;-682;

(and `5120.2-5482.0 = -361.8`...)

Edit : after seeing the comments this solution works for the first element. So you can iterate the process by changing `v[1],v[2],...`.

**Behaviour 1 (as Quentin's answer)**

```
std::vector<float> v{5120.2, 5140.2, 5500.2, 5482.0, 5802.2};
std::vector<float> result;
size_t size = v.size();
for (size_t i = 0; i < size; i ++) { result.insert(result.end(), v.begin(), v.end()); }
for (size_t i = 0; i < size; i ++) {
    std::transform(v.begin(), v.end(), result.begin() + i*size, [&](float a) { return v[i] - a; });
}
```

**<kbd>[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a3ed2bc649251c46)</kbd>**

Result given is :

> 0;-20;-380;-361.8;-682;20;0;-360;-341.8;-662;380;360;0;18.2002;-302;361.8;341.8;-18.2002;0;-320.2;682;662;302;320.2;0;

**Behaviour 2 (as m.s. answer)**

So I also tried to reproduce this other behaviour note the tricky index part, which is not that elegant...

```
std::vector<float> v{5120.2, 5140.2, 5500.2, 5482.0, 5802.2};
std::vector<float> result;
size_t size = v.size();
for (size_t i = 1; i < size; i ++) { result.insert(result.end(), v.begin() + i, v.end()); }
size_t sum = size*(size-1)/2;
for (size_t i = 0; i < size - 1; i ++) {
    std::transform(v.begin() + i + 1, v.end(), result.begin() + sum - (size-i)*(size-i-1)/2, [&](float a) { return v[i] - a; });
}
```

**<kbd>[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1a19729a00bada0b)</kbd>**
Result given is :

> -20;-380;-361.8;-682;-360;-341.8;-662;18.2002;-302;-320.2;

Comment: I would prefer one line result vector.

Comment: Sorry I did not understand your question can you reformulate ? 
Btw, I will try to edit my solution to follow your example if I have time.

Comment: No need to change the code,I can compile it.But how to see the result?Where to put std::cout ?

Comment: You have that in the [live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a3ed2bc649251c46) given below the code. I just print every element in the vector like this : `for (auto c : result) { std::cout << c << ";"; }`

Comment: Thanks a lot,I see now!

Comment: Great :) I added the other behaviour as m.s. answer. Wanted to have some fun while by sticking with std::transform.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `combine_pairwise` from [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/23287):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template<typename Iter, typename Func>
void combine_pairwise(Iter first, Iter last, Func func)
{
    for(; first != last; ++first)
        for(Iter next = std::next(first); next != last; ++next)
            func(*first, *next);
}

int main() {
    std::vector<float> v {5120.2, 5140.2, 5500.2, 5482.0, 5802.2};
    std::vector<float> result;

    auto op = [&](const float&f1, const float&f2){result.push_back(f1-f2);};
    combine_pairwise(v.begin(), v.end(), op);

    for (auto f : result)
    {
        std::cout << f << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

[<kbd>live on ideone</kbd>](https://ideone.com/i70Sk6)

Comment: @RichardRublev This iterates over unordered pairs. You specified ordered pairs.

Answer (score 2):

```
// New vector with enough space to hold the result
decltype(v1) v2;
v2.reserve(v.size() * v.size());

// Iterate over all possible pairs of (v × v)
auto ite = std::back_inserter(v2);
for(auto i1 : v)
    for(auto i2 : v)
        *ite++ = i1 - i2;

// Put the results back in v and let v2 die
swap(v, v2);
```

[Live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/992e3d185373d040)

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you want something like this.
Define a subtract function

```
float subtract(float first, float second)
{
    return first - second;
}
```

Then where you want to do the transform:

```
std::transform (v.begin(), --v.end(), ++v.begin(), result_vector.begin(), subtract);
```

If using C++14 you can just use [std::minus< float >](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/minus) instead of your own subtract

Comment: You may use `std::adjacent_difference` for that.